# How insert array to database in open cart?

Tags: arrays, foreach, insert, opencart

I build dynamic input by add row table, and user input by autocomplete, then I store **PRODUCT_ID** in `<input name="idp" value="">`

**E.g** User input twice times (HP & Computer)

Name Product | PRODUCT_ID

1. HP = 2945
2. COMPUTER = 8654

Should be in array is = (2945,8654)

This is for Controller:

```
class ControllerItemItem extends Controller { //Controller/Item/Item.php
private $error = array(); 
 
public function index() {
    $this->language->load('item/item');
    
    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title')); 
    
    $this->load->model('item/item');
    
    $this->getList();
}

protected function getList(){
    
    if (isset($this->request->get['head_text_field'])){
        $head_text_field = $this->request->get['head_text_field'];
    } else {
        $head_text_field = null;
    }
    
    if (isset($this->request->get['title_text_field'])){
        $title_text_field = $this->request->get['title_text_field'];
    } else {
        $title_text_field = null;
    }
    
    if (isset($this->request->get['max'])){
        $max = $this->request->get['max'];
    } else {
        $max = null;
    }
    
    if(isset($this->request->get['idp'])){ 
        $product = $this->request->get['idp'];
        $product2 = array();
        foreach($product as $p)
        {
            $product2[] = $p;
        }

    }else {
        $product = null;
    }
    
    
    // BREADCRUMBS //
    $this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

    $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
        'href'      => $this->url->link('common/home', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
        'separator' => false
    );

    $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text'      => $this->language->get('text_module'),
        'href'      => $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
        'separator' => ' :: '
    );

    $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text'      => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
        'href'      => $this->url->link('module/item', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
        'separator' => ' :: '
    );
    // END //
    
    // Call Language //
    $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
    $this->data['entry_head'] = $this->language->get('entry_head');
    $this->data['entry_title'] = $this->language->get('entry_title');
    $this->data['entry_product'] = $this->language->get('entry_product');
    $this->data['entry_max_item'] = $this->language->get('entry_max_item');
    $this->data['button_save'] = $this->language->get('button_save');
    $this->data['button_cancel'] = $this->language->get('button_cancel');
    // END //
    
    $this->data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');
    $this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('item/item/insert', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');
    $this->data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];

    
    $data   =   array(
        'head_text_field'   =>  $head_text_field,
        'title_text_field'  =>  $title_text_field,
        'max'               =>  $max
    );
    
    $this->template = 'item/item.tpl';
    $this->children = array(
        'common/header',
        'common/footer'
    );
    
    $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
        
}

public function insert()
{
    
    $this->language->load('item/item');
    
    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title')); 
    
    $this->load->model('item/item');
    
    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validateForm()) {
        //$this->model_item_item->insert_head($this->request->post);
        $this->model_item_item->insert_detail($this->request->post);
        
        //$this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
        //$this->redirect($this->url->link('item/item', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
    }
}

protected function validateForm() {
    if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'item/item')) {
        $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
    }

    if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['head_text_field']) < 1) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['head_text_field']) > 64)) {
        $this->error['head'] = $this->language->get('error_head');
    }
    
    if (!$this->request->post['title_text_field']) {
        $this->error['title'] = $this->language->get('error_title');
    }
                
    if (!$this->error) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is for Model :

```
class ModelItemItem extends Model { 
public function insert_head($data)
{
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "show_product SET head_text = '" . $this->db->escape($data['head_text_field']) . "', title_text = '" . $this->db->escape($data['title_text_field']) . "', max_item = '" . $this->db->escape($data['max']) . "'");
}

public function insert_detail($product2)
{
    foreach($product2 as $detail)
    {
        //$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "show_product_detail SET product_id = '". $this->db->escape($detail['product']) . "'");
    }
    echo $detail[0];
}
```

}

This is for view :

```
    <?php echo $header; ?>
<div id="content">
  <div class="breadcrumb">
    <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
    <?php echo $breadcrumb['separator']; ?><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
  <div class="warning"><?php echo $error_warning; ?></div>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php if ($success) { ?>
  <div class="success"><?php echo $success; ?></div>
  <?php } ?>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="heading">
      <h1><img src="view/image/product.png" alt="" /> <?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
      <div class="buttons"><a onclick="$('#form').submit();" class="button"><?php echo $button_save; ?></a><a href="<?php echo $cancel; ?>" class="button"><?php echo $button_cancel; ?></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
        <table class="form">
        <tr>
            <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_head; ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="head_text_field" value="" placeholder="Input Head Text" size="40"/>
                <?php if ($error_head) { ?>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $error_head; ?></span>
                <?php } ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_title; ?></td>
            <td><textarea name="title_text_field" placeholder="Input Title Text" style="width:230px;"/></textarea>
                <?php if ($error_title) { ?>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $error_title; ?></span>
                <?php } ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $entry_max_item; ?></td>
            <td>
                <select name="max" id="maxitem">
                <?php
                for($i=1; $i<=6; $i++)
                {
                    if($i == 1)
                        echo "<option selected='selected' value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
                    else
                        echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
                }
                ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $entry_product; ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="product" name="product" value="" placeholder="Input Product" size="40"/></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" id="idp" name="idp" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" id="ADD" value="Add Item"></td>
                    <td><input type="reset" id="RESET" value="Reset"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            
        </tr>
        </table>

        <table border="1" id="tblname" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Total Item
                </td>
                <td>
                    Id Item
                </td>
                <td>
                    Name Item
                </td>
                <td>
                    DELETE
                </td>
            <tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody align="center">
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('input[name=\'product\']').autocomplete({
    delay: 100,
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=catalog/product/autocomplete&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&filter_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(request.term),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {       
                response($.map(json, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.name,
                        value: item.product_id
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    }, 
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('input[name=\'product\']').val(ui.item.label);
        $('input[name=\'idp\']').val(ui.item.value);
        return false;
    },
    
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        return false;
    }
});

//--></script>
<Script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var item = 1;
    var isAllowed   = 3;
    var isSet       = 0;
    $('#ADD').click(function(){
        var maxitem = parseInt($("#maxitem").val(), 10); //from max item in html
        var iCount = 0;
        if($('#product').val()){  // check input product
            if( item <= maxitem )
            {
                iCount = $('#tblname tbody tr').length + 1;
                szTr = "<tr><td>";
                szTr = szTr + iCount + "</td>";
                szTr = szTr +   "<td>" +$('#idp').val() +"</td>";
                szTr = szTr +   "<td>" +$('#product').val() +"</td>";
                szTr = szTr +   "<td><input type='button' class='DEL' value='DELETE'></td>";
                szTr = szTr +   "</tr>";                     
                $('#tblname tbody').append(szTr);
                item +=1;
                isSet = 1;
                restFormOpts();
            }
            else
            {
                alert ("Max Limit !!!");
            }
        }else{alert('Enter Product !!! ');}
    });

    // for delete row
    $('body').on('click','#RESET', function() {
        item        = 1;
        isAllowed   = 3;
        isSet       = 0;
        $("#maxitem").attr("disabled",false);
        $('.DEL').parents('tr').remove();
    });
    
    $('body').on('click', 'input.DEL', function() {
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();  
        item -= 1;
    });
    
    function restFormOpts()
    {
        if(isSet === isAllowed) {
            $("#ADD").attr("disabled",true);
            $("#maxitem").attr("disabled",false);
        }
        else {
            $("#ADD").attr("disabled",false);
            $("#maxitem").attr("disabled",true);
        }
    }
});
</script>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

When I try insert query to my database, value only 1 number.

Then I try Echo for make sure variable is correct but it's wrong, the result is the last user input (Computer, in array(8,6,5,4))?  it's should be (2945,8654) not (8,6,5,4)?

Can some one help me for fix this?? I already try fix this problem for 1 week still no hope :(

Comment: are you want to insert array to database ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert `array variables` in `database`, First you need encode them and then insert them .

Ex. $abc = array(3,45,6,78,89) ;

Query : `"INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "show_product_detail SET product_id = '". $this->db->escape(json_encode($abc)) . "'`

Comment: How I can encode if the input is dynamic, i try store but it's result only 1 number(should be 4), did i mistake in store input?

Comment: i try $temp = count($this->request->get['idp']);
   $idp = $this->request->get['idp'];
   for($i=0; $i<$temp; $i++)
   {
    $product2 = array (
     'idp' => $idp[$i],
    );
   } still same result like before